# FontAwesome icons are higher up in Safari than Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, font-awesome

I don't know why this is happening, but my FontAwesome icons are appearing offset in Safari.

In Chrome they look like this:

[image]

In Safari, like this:

[image]

Now, I'm using Foundation, React.js, and FontAwesome, so providing the CSS via JSFiddle proved very cumbersome. I tried to skin off as much as I can and make it barebones, and I believe you can still see it happening in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tdk6qhsd/1/). Just look at it in Safari and then in Chrome and you should notice an offset.

Here is the JSFiddle laid out here:

HTML:

```
<div class="line">
  <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
  <span class="name" >cfb</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.line {
    color: #60b0c6;
    text-transform: capitalize; 
}

.name {
    font-size: 13px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 93%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 6px;
    left: 2px; 
}

.fa-cog {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #333; 
}

.fa {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; 
}
```

I have no idea how to fix this and am very puzzled.

**Edit: Vertical align does not work on my end.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `vertical-align` fixes it:

```
.fa {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    vertical-align: middle; /* Or try bottom or baseline */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, this was a line height issue. Setting `line-height: inherit` for my FontAwesome icon nudged it back down into a vertically centered position. This doesn't seem to impact rendering in other browsers, but it fixes the positioning problem in Safari.

Answer (score -1):

I think you could achieve that by defining `vertical-align: middle`.

Answer (score -1):

Remove `top` and `left` from `.name` class and give `vertical-align`  will do the trick.

Here i use  `vertical-align:top;`

```
.name {
    font-size: 13px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 93%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align:top; //Here.
}

.fa {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top; // Here
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tdk6qhsd/5/)** Checked in Firefox, Chrome, Safari.

Comment: Where i say remove `position:relative` ?

Comment: Could be my brain not working correctly. LoL. Sorry dude.